# Usecase of ExtractedText

Tags: android, android-extracted-text

I am trying to understand `ExtractedText` from official documentation as could not find any other blogs/materials online and seems technical documentation is heavy load of jargons.

Can anybody please explain me the usecase/purpose of it? Only thing I got to know is it can be used in case of fullscreenmode to show extracted portion of text when user types but I need to know more practical scenario with better explanation.

Referred links:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/ExtractedText

Answer (score 0):

Please check here.

[What's the Android "Extracted Text UI"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906053/whats-the-android-extracted-text-ui)

In short : It's for low resolution small size screen device, to make user convenient to edit on landscape screen.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo#IME_FLAG_NO_ACCESSORY_ACTION

" Setting this generally means that you think that in fullscreen mode, where there is little space to show the text, it's not worth taking some screen real estate to display the action and it should be used instead to show more text."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo#ME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI

" For input methods that may be fullscreen, often when in landscape mode, this allows them to be smaller and let part of the application be shown behind, through transparent UI parts in the fullscreen IME. The part of the UI visible to the user may not be responsive to touch because the IME will receive touch events, which may confuse the user; use IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN instead for a better experience. "